# Convocar procedimiento almacenado en sql desde Java

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedure

Quisiera saber  que estoy haciendo mal, al devolver un ResultSet que me ejecuta un procedimiento almacenado que realiza un select en una tabla sql. Estoy trabajando en Java

tengo un proyecto java que sirve como capa de datos donde realizo la conexión a la base de datos y recibe los parametro de la capa de presentacion para convocar y enviar dichos datos a la BD sql, despues el proceso TraerProducto debe devolver el ResultSet a otro proyecto java, que seria la capa de datos, donde esta la tabla.

```
package Conectar;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Driver; 
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet; 
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement; 
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.sql.CallableStatement;   
import java.sql.Types;  


public class Coneccion
{
        static String login="";
        static String Password="";
        Connection conexion=null;
        String driver="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver";
        CallableStatement cst;
        ResultSet r;
        Statement sentencia;
        Coneccion con;

    public Coneccion()
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driver);
            conexion=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName= NEGOCIO", "sa", "123");
        }
        catch(SQLException | ClassNotFoundException e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
    }

    public Connection getConnection()
    {
        return conexion;
    }

    public void desconectar()
    {
        conexion=null;
        if(conexion!=null)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "No se pudo cerra la conexion");
        }
    }

    public ResultSet Listar (String Cad)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection cn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName= NEGOCIO", "sa", "123");
            PreparedStatement da= cn.prepareStatement(Cad);
            ResultSet tbl= da.executeQuery();
            return tbl;
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e)
        {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return null;
        }
    }


    public String Ejecutar (String Cad)
    {
        try
        {
            Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
            Connection cn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433; databaseName= NEGOCIO", "sa", "123");
            PreparedStatement da= cn.prepareStatement(Cad);

            ResultSet r = da.executeQuery();
            return "Registro Grabados con exito";
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | SQLException e)
        {
            javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
            return "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }

    }



    public ResultSet TraerProducto(int id, String nombre, int m) {
        try
        {
            Coneccion obj= new Coneccion();

            PreparedStatement pstm= con.getConnection().prepareStatement("{call TraerProducto ?, ?}");
            pstm.setInt(1, id);
            pstm.setString(2, nombre);

            ResultSet consulta = pstm.executeQuery();

            ResultSet r=obj.Listar(String.valueOf(consulta));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
        }
        return r;
    }
}
```

Este es el procedimiento que convoca a TraerProducto de la capa de datos, y cargar el resultado en la jtable. El procedieminto se ejecuta cada vez que se ingresan datos en un Jtext:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) 
    {
        if (textBuscarP.getText().length()>3)
        {
                String eleccion=String.valueOf(comboBoxFiltroP.getSelectedIndex());

                if(eleccion=="CODIGO")
                {
                    m=1;
                }
                else
                {
                    m=0;
                }


                Coneccion objeto= new Coneccion();
                ResultSet r;


                if (m==1)
                {
                    r = objeto.TraerProducto(Integer.parseInt(this.textBuscarP.getText()), "", m);

                }
                else
                {
                    r= objeto.TraerProducto(-10, this.textBuscarP.getText(), m);
                }

                try
                {
                    String titulos[]= {"ID","Nombre","Precio","Cantidad","Precio de Descuento", "Cantidad de Descuento","Codigo de Barra"};
                    DefaultTableModel m1 = new DefaultTableModel(null, titulos);
                    JTable p= new JTable (m1);
                    String fila[]= new String[7];
                    int c=1;

                    while (r.next())
                    {
                        fila[1]=r.getString(1);
                        fila[2]=r.getString(2);
                        fila[3]=r.getString(3);
                        fila[4]=r.getString(4);
                        fila[5]=r.getString(5);
                        fila[6]=r.getString(6);
                        m1.addRow(fila);
                        c++;
                    }
                    TablaProducto.setModel(m1);
                    TableRowSorter<TableModel> ordenar= new TableRowSorter<TableModel> (m1);
                    TablaProducto.setRowSorter(ordenar);
                    this.TablaProducto.setModel(m1);
                }
                catch(Exception e1)
                {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Cual es el error especifico que te arroja la aplicacion??

Comment: Tal como comenta @juandej18 deberías se mas específico con el error que te ocurre. Yo de un primer vistazo veo que las llamadas a procedimientos almacenados se realizan mediante CallableStatement stmt = getConnection().dbConnection.prepareCall("{call TraerProducto (?, ?)}")